# Unexpected template string while trying to create dynamic object in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to require Controllers dynamically.

Here is my entity object:-

```
ENTITY : {
          USER            : 'user',
          COUNTRY         : 'country'
}
```

Based on it, I am trying to hae the controllers. Here is my code:-

```
for (var key in ENTITY) {
    if (ENTITY.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const controllerName        = MiscHelp.camelCase(ENTITY[key], true) + 'Controller';
        console.log(controllerName);
        const controllerFile        = '../app/Http/Controllers/' + version  + '/' + controllerName;
        console.log(controllerFile);
        const `${controllerName}`   = require(controllerFile)(version);
    }       
}
```

The console displays this:-

```
UserController
../app/Http/Controllers/v1/UserController
CountryController
../app/Http/Controllers/v1/CountryController
```

However, this LOC

```
const `${controllerName}`   = require(controllerFile)(version);
```

is giving me "Unexpected Template String" error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some workarounds to create dynamic variable names, but I don't recommend using them.
I recommend you to use an object.

```js
for (var key in ENTITY) {
    if (ENTITY.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const controller = {
            name: MiscHelp.camelCase(ENTITY[key], true) + 'Controller',
            file: '../app/Http/Controllers/' + version  + '/' + controllerName,
            version: require(controllerFile)(version)
        }

        // Use controller as you wish
    }       
}
```

---

If you really **really** really want to create dynamic variable names, use

```js
eval(`const ${controller.name} = require(controllerFile)(version);`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `dynamic-imports` using `import` and you can pass the `filenames` as string.

`axios-req.js` and `node-fetch-req.js` are 2 different `commonjs` modules imported dynamically in `index.js`

**axios-req.js**

```
const axios = require("axios");

exports.func = (id) => {
  axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`).then((d) => console.log(d.data));
};
```

**node-fetch-req.js**

```
exports.apiFunc = (id) => {
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json));
};
```

**index.js**

```
const fetchModule = "./node-fetch-req.js";
const axiosModule = "./axios-req.js";
const main = async (mode = "a") => {
  if (mode == "f") {
    const { apiFunc } = await import(fetchModule);
    apiFunc(4);
  } else {
    const { func } = await import(axiosModule);
    func(2);
  }
};
main("f");
```